# I'm trying to send text to an instance of QTermWidget and artificially press enter for the user

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using `QTermWidget` as an embedded terminal within my c++/qt4 project and I'm having trouble emulating a return/enter key press on the terminal. I've spent a few hours on Google looking for anything I could find and through all of the source code for `QTermWidget`.

I've tried

```
    QKeyEvent key(QEvent::KeyPress,Qt::Key_Return, Qt::NoModifier);
    QApplication::postEvent(console, &key);
```

and

```
    QKeyEvent key(QEvent::KeyPress,Qt::Key_Return, Qt::NoModifier);
    QCoreApplication::postEvent(console, &key);
```

as well but using `QApplication::sendEvent()` and `QCoreApplication::sendEvent()` respectively, with *console* being the instance of `QTermWidget`. I am trying to manipulate.

I've also tried

```
    QKeyEvent key(QKeyEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_Return, Qt::NoModifer);
```

I'm a newbie so please bear with me, and thank you for all your help.

Comment: have you tried `void QtermWidget::sendText(QString & text);`

Comment: Yes, I am currently using that to send the text to my instance of QTermWidget, but currently the only way to return the text send to the terminal is by clicking onto the terminal and pressing the enter/return key. I'm hoping to find a way to send the text ( using QTermWidget::sendText() ) and then automatically have the text inputted by simulating a key press

Answer (score 1):

I eventually found the answer to this, it is the send an escape sequence to the instance of QTermWidget

QTermWidget::sendText('\r')